# If Statement inside Sinatra template

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'd like to to show a message only if on a specific route/page.  Essentially, if on /route display a message.

I tried going through the Sinatra Docs, but I can't find a specific way to do it.  Is there a Ruby method that will make this work?

EDIT: Here's an example of what I'd like to do.

```
get '/' do
    erb :index
end

get '/page1' do
    erb :page1
end

get '/page2' do
    erb :page2
end

*******************

<!-- Layout File -->
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head> 
<body>
    <% if this page is 'page1' do something %>
    <% else do something else %>
    <% end %>

    <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

No idea what how to target the current page using Ruby/Sinatra and structure it into an if statement.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but what doesn't work about `get '/route' do; 'your message'; end`?

Comment: Could you post your current code?

Comment: Why aren't you puting the code the if statement would yield inside each template?

Comment: @nicooga I haven't written it yet.  I don't know how to target a specific page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this (and BTW, I'm going to use [Haml](http://haml.info/) even though you've used ERB because it's less typing for me and plainly an improvement). Most of them rely on the [request helper](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object), most often it will be `request.path_info`.

#### Conditional within a view.

Within any view, not just a layout:

```
%p
  - if request.path_info == "/page1"
    = "You are on page1"
  - else
    = "You are not on page1, but on #{request.path_info[1..]}"
%p= request.path_info == "/page1" ? "PAGE1!!!" : "NOT PAGE1!!!"
```

#### A conditional with a route.

```
get "/page1" do
  # you are on page1
  message = "This is page 1"
  # you can use an instance variable if you want, 
  # but reducing scope is a best practice and very easy.
  erb :page1, :locals => { message: message }
end

get "/page2" do
  message = nil # not needed, but this is a silly example
  erb :page2, :locals => { message: message }
end

get %r{/page(\d+)} do |digits|
  # you'd never reach this with a 1 as the digit, but again, this is an example
  message = "Page 1" if digits == "1"
  erb :page_any, :locals => { message: message }
end

# page1.erb
%p= message unless message.nil?
```

#### A `before` block.

```
before do
  @message = "Page1" if request.path_info == "/page1"
end

# page1.erb
%p= @message unless @message.nil?
```

or even better

```
before "/page1" do
  @message = "Hello, this is page 1"
end
```

or better again

```
before do
  @message = request.path_info == "/page1" ? "PAGE 1!" : "NOT PAGE 1!!"
end

# page1.erb
%p= @message
```

I would also suggest you take a look at [Sinatra Partial](https://github.com/yb66/Sinatra-Partial) if you're looking to do this, as it's a lot easier to handle splitting up views when you have a helper ready made for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Sinatra has no "controller#action" Rail's like concept, so you wont find a way to instantiate the current route. In any case, you can check `request.path.split('/').last` to get a *relative idea* of what is the current route.

However, if you want something so be shown only `if request.path == "x"`, a much better way is to put that content on the template, unless that content has to be rendered in a different place within your layout. In that case you can use something like Rail's `content_for`. Check [sinatra-content-for](https://github.com/foca/sinatra-content-for).

Comment: You've a typo, it should be equality not assignment i.e. `if request.path == "x"`. Also, there is a better helper attribute to use that `.path` in `.path_info`, so no need for the `.split('/').last`. See [Accessing the Request Object](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object) from the docs.