# Passing if result to erb view in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I'm trying to pass the result of (if ... else) to .erb file
for example

```
if @p
 "show something"
else    
 "show other thing"
end
```

How could I do it?
Thanks

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079193/if-statement-inside-sinatra-template

Comment: It is written in haml, but I'm using .erb, and I tried it, but it doesn't work. thanks

Comment: sorry.. that I didn't check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way of passing values to the view in Sinatra is by using instance variables. Any instance variable you set in your route will be available in the view. So in this case you could do something like this:

```
@my_variable = if @p
 "show something"
else    
 "show other thing"
end
```

and then in your Erb view:

```erb
<%= @my_variable %>
```

The result will be that either `show something` or `show other thing` will appear in the rendered page depending on the value of `@p`.

Comment: If you found that answer helped you out it's considered polite to accept it. ;)

Comment: Sure Jack, I'm sorry, I'm just a newbie here, but I've done it. Thanks for tip.